# Xcode 9.3 Autocomplete for NSManagedObject Subclass not working?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I created a new `.xcdatamodeld` file (`New File > Core Data > Data Model`). I created an entity let's call it `SomeEntityName`and I added its attributes. From there I'm creating an `NSManagedObject` in `Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass...`. The creation works and I see the `SomeEntityName+CoreDataClass.swift` and `SomeEntityName+CoreDataProperties.swift` files but, the autocomplete is not working?

I have restarted Xcode, cleaned, rebuilt the project and still no luck.

I tried to change the `Codegen` to `Manual/None` from `Class Definition` in the right panel core data inspector but that gives me an error of an `undeclared type "EntityName"`

Is there something I am missing?

**Edit**: In my other Class files, I am able to autocomplete subclass definitions like `Codable` or `import Foundation`, etc.

Comment: Is the name of your entity actually “EntityName”?

Comment: Please provide actual instructions for reproducing the problem. No one knows what you are typing such that you expect autocompletion. Tell us how to create a sample project and what to type and where to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Sorry matt I edited my post hopefully it is more clear...

Comment: I saw this once when I created a "blank swift file".  I ended up deleting it and pasting my code into a "new cocoa class".  I inferred there was some meta-data somewhere involved.  But I never followed up to figure out exactly what had happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a couple hours managed to figure out the issue, hopefully no one else runs into this as well:

By default when selecting your `.xcdatamodeld` file in the project navigator and creating an NSManagedObject via `Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass...` the location had no targets selected. You need to select your project and make sure the **target** is checked.

[image]

Comment: Quite clearly shown in the instructions from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1952/_index.html

Comment: Thanks matt, my GoogleFu skills were lacking today

Comment: So you weren't missing autocomplete; you were missing the entities as classes altogether (or at least their attributes as properties). Isn't that true?